# Adding a simple toggle configuration for Watch Face (Android Wear)

Tags: android, wear-os

In creating a watch face for Android Wear, I would like to have a simple configuration (a toggle switch?) that set which mode the user wanted the watch face to looks like (for example, white or black watch face).

I would prefer the toggle switch to be on the watch itself, prefer not to communicate with the phone for such simple action, and hopefully to avoid all the GoogleApiClient communications between watch and phones. Is there a way to do this easily, similar to doing Settings or SharedPreferences on Android?

I tried using a Broadcast receiver. I can get the changes in Broadcast receiver, but how do I get the CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine to update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.
You have to follow [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/configuration.html).

First Create an `Activity` displaying the settings you want the user to change.

Then in your Manifest file, add this meta data to your Watchface service:

```
<meta-data
    android:name=
       "com.google.android.wearable.watchface.wearableConfigurationAction"
    android:value=
       "com.example.android.wearable.watchface.CONFIG_DIGITAL" />
```

And this `IntentFilter` to your `Activity`:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name=
            "com.example.android.wearable.watchface.CONFIG_DIGITAL" />
        <category android:name=
       "com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.WEARABLE_CONFIGURATION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Of course, you will have to replace "com.example.android" by your package name.

Then a small setting icon will appear below your watchface preview in the Watchface selector screen.

Do not forget to synchronize the setting between your Activity and Watchface in order to make it appear instantly (with a `BroadcastReceiver` for example)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do know it is possible to do the wearable configuration part, what I am asking is the last part "synchronisation between Activity and Watch face" (any info/documentation on this)?

Comment: There is no universal solution for that. You can use a Broadcast receiver in your watchface and send a broadcast intent in your activity with your value in an extra.

Comment: Thanks, let me give it a try.

Comment: I tried. Putting broadcast receiver in the watch face service or the engine, both does not seem to received the message sent. I put my example codes in the question.

Comment: By convention, your action should start by your package name. Did you add this action in an intentfilter for your service in the manifest?

Comment: I register it in codes, should I still register in manifest? I thought it is one way or another.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I misread your code. You just din't send the Intent in your activity. Just add `sendBroadcast(intent);` before the `finish();` line

Answer (score 1):

I addressed this with a [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) that registers 3 intents

- Get Initial Data, sent from Config Activity, expected by Watch Service
- Initial Data, sent by Watch Service in response to the message above
- Data Changed, sent by Config Activity when user makes selections.

Everything is wrapped in a single class which exposes two interfaces for interactions (one for Watch Service, the other for Config Activity. Probably not the easiest solution but the best I could come up with after 3 days of digging :(

For the record, here is the class sharing 2 variables (bezelMode and time24).
You will need to instantiate it from your watch service (implementing WatchConfig.Service) and you configuration activity (implementing WatchConfig.Editor)
Communication is based on LocalBroadcastManager

```
public class WatchConfig {
//    private static final String TAG = "Config";

    // Used when data has changed
    public static final String CONFIG_DATA_CHANGED = "/config/changed";
    // Used to provide initial data
    public static final String CONFIG_INITIAL_DATA = "/config/inital-data";
    // Used to query initial data
    public static final String CONFIG_INITIAL_QUERY = "/config/initial-query";

    private int m_BezelMode;
    private boolean m_Time24;

    private LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager;
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiverDataChanged;
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiverInitialDataRequest;
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiverInitialData;

    private Service service;
    private Editor editor;

    WatchConfig(Context context, Service service) {
        initialize( context, service, null);
    }

    WatchConfig(Context context, Editor editor) {
        initialize( context, null, editor);
    }

    void initialize( Context context, Service service, Editor editor) {
        this.localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance( context);

        this.service = service;
        this.editor = editor;
    }

    interface Service {
        void onConfigDataUpdated(boolean time24, int bezelMode);
        void onConfigInitialRequest();
    }

    interface Editor {
        void onConfigInitialize(boolean time24, int bezelMode);
    }

    /**
     * Registers all proper receivers
     */
    public void connect() {
        if( this.service != null) {
            IntentFilter intentFilterDataChanged = new IntentFilter(CONFIG_DATA_CHANGED);
            this.broadcastReceiverDataChanged = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//                    Log.d(TAG,"Data Changed Notification");
                    service.onConfigDataUpdated(intent.getBooleanExtra("time24", true), intent.getIntExtra("bezel", 24));
                }
            };
            this.localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverDataChanged, intentFilterDataChanged);

            IntentFilter intentFilterInitialDataRequesy = new IntentFilter(CONFIG_INITIAL_QUERY);
            this.broadcastReceiverInitialDataRequest = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//                    Log.d(TAG,"Initial Query Notification");
                    service.onConfigInitialRequest();
                }
            };
            this.localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverInitialDataRequest, intentFilterInitialDataRequesy);
        } else {
            this.broadcastReceiverDataChanged = null;
            this.broadcastReceiverInitialDataRequest = null;
        }
        if( this.editor != null) {
            IntentFilter intentFilterInitalData = new IntentFilter(CONFIG_INITIAL_DATA);
            this.broadcastReceiverInitialData = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//                    Log.d(TAG,"Initial Data notification");
                    editor.onConfigInitialize(intent.getBooleanExtra("time24", true), intent.getIntExtra("bezel", 24));
                }
            };
            this.localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverInitialData, intentFilterInitalData);

            // Editors need intial data
            Intent intentInitialDataRequest = new Intent( CONFIG_INITIAL_QUERY);
            this.localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast( intentInitialDataRequest);
        } else {
            this.broadcastReceiverInitialData = null;
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        if( this.broadcastReceiverDataChanged != null) {
            this.localBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(this.broadcastReceiverDataChanged);
        }
        if( this.broadcastReceiverInitialDataRequest != null) {
            this.localBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(this.broadcastReceiverInitialDataRequest);
        }
        if( this.broadcastReceiverInitialData != null) {
            this.localBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(this.broadcastReceiverInitialData);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used to publish changes in configuration
     */
    protected void publishInitialData(boolean time24, int bezel) {
        this.m_Time24 = time24;
        this.m_BezelMode = bezel;

        Intent intent = new Intent( CONFIG_INITIAL_DATA);
        intent.putExtra("time24", this.m_Time24);
        intent.putExtra("bezel", this.m_BezelMode);
        this.localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Used to publish changes in configuration
     */
    protected void publishUpdate() {
        Intent intent = new Intent( CONFIG_DATA_CHANGED);
        intent.putExtra("time24", this.m_Time24);
        intent.putExtra("bezel", this.m_BezelMode);
        this.localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public void setTime24(boolean time24) {
        this.m_Time24 = time24;
    }

    public void setBezelMode(int bezelMode) {
        this.m_BezelMode = bezelMode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey great! Thanks for sharing. I was looking and looking so much for something similar. Great answer although its a bit more cody, but combining both it's great!